# inherit `Java.Lang.Object` Error in Xamarin Android app

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, google-maps, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin and visual studio.I have visual studio 2017 and I am developing Google Map Android Project.

I am getting this error:

error XA4212:  Type `Android.Support.V4.App.JobIntentService/JobServiceEngineImpl` implements `Android.Runtime.IJavaObject` but does not inherit `Java.Lang.Object` or `Java.Lang.Throwable`. This is not supported.

```
 My MainActivity.cs is 

    using Android.App;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Gms.Maps;

    namespace App1
    {
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true)]

        public class MainActiity: Activity, IOnMapReadyCallback

        {
            private GoogleMap GMap;
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

                // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                SetUpMap();
            }
            private void SetUpMap()
            {
                if (GMap == null)
                {
                    FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.googlemap).GetMapAsync(this);
                }
            }
            public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
            {
                this.GMap = googleMap;
            }
            }
          }
```

and in main.axml, I have fragment under linear layout for the map. do help me to get rid of this error.

Comment: on which line do you get this

Comment: Could you please try it in an empty blank app without google map?

Comment: I have taken blank app only. and I didn't understand "without google map?" can you give some clarification? @ElvisXia

Comment: I mean without referencing the google map library in your project. I tried with only support library in my blank project, but failed to reproduce the problem. Could you share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?